# Simultaneous eventListeners on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I built a simple input group using bootstrap and am trying to make the "Run / Go" button only clickable once all input was passed in:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Input one -->
  <div class="custom-file">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="input-one">Input One</label>
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control-file" id="input-one" required>
  </div>

  <!-- Input two -->
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="input-two">Input Two</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" id="input-two" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- Run button -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 disabled" id="btn-run">Run</button>
</div>
```

As shown above, the "Run / Go" button is disabled by default. I can use javascript to enable the button. In the case of just one input I would do the following:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let runBtn = document.getElementById('btn-run');
  let inputOne = document.getElementById('input-one');

  inputOne.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    let classes = runBtn.classList;
    classes.remove('disabled');
    runBtn.className = classes;
    runBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // Run stuff
  }
}
```

This works perfectly - however - if I add another input and nest the eventListeners I have to define an order of execution (highest -> most nested) which is not desired. I therefore wanted to know if I can add eventListeners to multiple elements? Or if there are more elegant alternatives?

I hope this made sense. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You need to approach this in an event & state based instead of a sequential way. The click listener for the run button should be assigned from the start (you are already disabling the button anyway). Next, the change listener for each input element should cause a validation function to run, and if the entire form passes, the run button gets its `disabled` attribute removed.

Comment: That makes sense. Would be be able to provide a small example so I know where to get started?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mx4167vt/

Comment: If you add it to the answers I can accept it. Thanks alot

Comment: This won't work for ```<input type="text">``` I guess.. It doesn't here https://jsfiddle.net/2qobtc79/1/